# How can I print a boolean value in PL SQL?

Tags: sql, plsql, case

```
DECLARE
    res BOOLEAN;
BEGIN 
    res:=p_overload_demo.update_dept('&input');
    CASE 
    WHEN res THEN dbms_output.put_line('True');
    WHEN NOT res THEN dbms_output.put_line('False');
    ELSE   dbms_output.put_line('INVALID');
    END CASE;
END;
```

Here p_overload_demo is the package and update_dept is the function in it.
When I execute these statements I get the result as "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed." but it doesn't print my CASE statements. Does anyone know if there is any simpler way of printing boolean value?

Comment: set serveroutput on?

Comment: Silly me...that was the problem. Thank you